# Display Y/N column if record found in detail table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query so that I can have a column show Y/N if a particular item was ordered for a group of orders.  The item I'm looking for would be OLI.id = '538'.

So my results would be:

```
Order#, Customer#, FreightPaid
12345, 00112233, Y
12346, 00112233, N
```

I cannot figure out if I need to use a subquery or the where exists function ?

Here's my current query:

```
    SELECT distinct
      OrderID,
      Accountuid as Customerno
  FROM [SMILEWEB_live].[dbo].[OrderLog] OL
  inner join Orderlog_item OLI on OLI.orderlogkey = OL.[key]
  inner join Account A on A.uid = OL.Accountuid
  where A.GroupId = 'X9955'
  and OL.CreateDate >= GETDATE() - 60
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an `exists` clause instead of a `join`:

```
select ol.OrderID, ol.Accountuid as Customerno,
       (case when exists (select 1 
                          from Orderlog_item OLI join
                               Account A
                               on A.uid = OL.Accountuid
                          where OLI.orderlogkey = OL.[key] and A.GroupId = 'X9955'
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from [SMILEWEB_live].[dbo].[OrderLog] OL
where OL.CreateDate >= GETDATE() - 60;
```

This prevents a couple of problems.  First, duplicate rows which are caused when there are multiple matching rows (and `select distinct` add unnecessary overhead).  Second, missing rows, which happen when you use inner join instead of an outer join.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of results for accounts that are not in the group X9955.  I'm also not seeing where it is checking for OL.ID = '538'

Comment: @MattC . . . Add a `where` clause in the subquery.